# Replace OAuth2AccessTokenJackson2Deserializer with my own custom deserializer

Tags: spring, spring-boot

This class is deserializing an oauth2 token and I would like to tweak it. I created my own class extending `StdDeserializer<OAuth2AccessToken>` which at the moment is the same as the original class.

Here is the class:

```
public class MyCustomDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<OAuth2AccessToken> {

public MyCustomDeserializer() {
    super(OAuth2AccessToken.class);
}

@Override
public OAuth2AccessToken deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException,
        JsonProcessingException {

    String tokenValue = null;
    String tokenType = null;
    String refreshToken = null;
    Long expiresIn = null;
    Set<String> scope = null;
    Map<String, Object> additionalInformation = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();

    // TODO What should occur if a parameter exists twice
    while (jp.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
        String name = jp.getCurrentName();
        jp.nextToken();
        if (OAuth2AccessToken.ACCESS_TOKEN.equals(name)) {
            tokenValue = jp.getText();
        }
        else if (OAuth2AccessToken.TOKEN_TYPE.equals(name)) {
            tokenType = jp.getText();
        }
        else if (OAuth2AccessToken.REFRESH_TOKEN.equals(name)) {
            refreshToken = jp.getText();
        }
        else if (OAuth2AccessToken.EXPIRES_IN.equals(name)) {
            try {
                expiresIn = jp.getLongValue();
            } catch (JsonParseException e) {
                expiresIn = Long.valueOf(jp.getText());
            }
        }
        else if (OAuth2AccessToken.SCOPE.equals(name)) {
            scope = parseScope(jp);
        } else {
            additionalInformation.put(name, jp.readValueAs(Object.class));
        }
    }

    // TODO What should occur if a required parameter (tokenValue or tokenType) is missing?

    DefaultOAuth2AccessToken accessToken = new DefaultOAuth2AccessToken(tokenValue);
    accessToken.setTokenType(tokenType);
    if (expiresIn != null) {
        accessToken.setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + (expiresIn * 1000)));
    }
    if (refreshToken != null) {
        accessToken.setRefreshToken(new DefaultOAuth2RefreshToken(refreshToken));
    }
    accessToken.setScope(scope);
    accessToken.setAdditionalInformation(additionalInformation);

    return accessToken;
}

private Set<String> parseScope(JsonParser jp) throws JsonParseException, IOException {
    Set<String> scope;
    if (jp.getCurrentToken() == JsonToken.START_ARRAY) {
        scope = new TreeSet<String>();
        while (jp.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_ARRAY) {
            scope.add(jp.getValueAsString());
        }
    } else {
        String text = jp.getText();
        scope = OAuth2Utils.parseParameterList(text);
    }
    return scope;
}
```

}

Here I am registering the bean:

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper configObjectMapper() {
    final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
    final SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("configModule",   com.fasterxml.jackson.core.Version.unknownVersion());
    module.addDeserializer(OAuth2AccessToken.class, new MyCustomDeserializer());
    objectMapper.registerModule(module);
    return objectMapper;
}
```

Testing the above code the flow doesn't reach my class but the original. I am using spring boot 2.1.4